# How to pass a functional component inside an event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have a form and I want the user to display the values user fills in the fields as a JSON object at the end when the user clicks the submit button.

In Form.js,

```
state={
group:[
type-A{col1: "",
col2:""
}
]
}


handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        <Credentials value={JSON.stringify(this.state)}/>
      }
change = e =>{
        this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    };
 render(){
        return(
            <div class="classform">
            <form >
             <label>
                    Column1:
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text"
                    name="group1"
                    placeholder="Column1"
                    value={this.state.column1}
                    onChange={e=> this.change(e)}
//other fields
//input form fields
 <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
```

In Credentials.js,

```
    return (
        <p>{value}</p>
    )
}

export default Credentials
```

The above code gives me an error, in handleSubmit() in second line `(<Credentials value={JSON.stringify(this.state)}/>)`

When the user clicks Submit button, I want to get a JSON object for the data entered in the input fields in the form and update it if the user updates any information in the fields.

Comment: move the component to render method. and use conditional rendering.

Comment: Do you want the user to stay on the same page when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the component to render method. and use conditional rendering.

```
state = {credentials: false}

handleSubmit = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  this.setState({
    credentials: true // display Credentials  component
  });

};

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
      {this.state.credentials && (
        <Credentials value={JSON.stringify(this.state)} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const Credentials = ({ value }) => {
  return <p>{value}</p>;
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { credentials: false };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      credentials: true // display Credentials  component
    });
  };

  change = e => {
    const name = e.target.name;

    const nameObj = {};
    nameObj[name] = e.target.value;

    this.setState({ ...nameObj });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="col1"
          value={this.state['col1']}
          onChange={e => this.change(e)}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        {this.state.credentials && (
          <Credentials value={JSON.stringify(this.state)} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}



ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this! It works but the problem with this is that, it displays the old state along with the new state which shouldn't happen! I get something like this:         
 {"group":[{"type_a":[{"col1":"","col2":""],"type_b":[{"col3":"","col4":""}]}],"credentials":true,"col1":"as","col2":"2019-05-15","col3":"as","col4":"as"}

Comment: but that's not old state, in the old state credentials was false.

Comment: yea, it is appending both the state together, instead of changing the values of the state. I want something like this. {"group":[{"type_a":[{"col1":"as","col2":"2012-11-12"],"type_b":[{"col3":"qw","col4":"ew"}]}]

Comment: where are you changing the values?

Comment: In this function, change = e =>{this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})};             which I am calling via: <input type="text"
                    name="col1"
                    value={this.state.col1}
                    onChange={e=> this.change(e)}
                 />

Comment: please add that function to the question.

Comment: I did, please have a look

Comment: change your function to `change = (e) => {
    this.setState({ col1: e.target.value })
  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193075/discussion-between-junius-l-and-user8306074).

Comment: @user8306074 I've added a demo.